# How to stop system update on Galaxy S8 with Android 7.0?

Tags: ota-update, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I have disabled auto updates through developer options, but the S8 is still pushing through the update. I have attempted to restart but the update continues. Is there any way to stop this while on wifi? It is a metered wifi connection, so I cannot have the update running, essentially making my phone unusable.